# Browser password managers have me stumped

Tags: html, passwords

I am working on a login dialog to my site.  To spare users the frustration of having to remember their login details, I want to cooperate with the built-in browser password managers.  I have worked out that to get Firefox to play ball, I must use a plain-vanilla HTML Form.  Fine, so be it.  However, I will not transfer unencrypted passwords.  So my form content looks like so:

```
input#1 type="text" name="login"
input#2 type="password"
input#3 type="hidden" name="passwd"
```

I then intercept the submit and encrypt the content of #2 into #3, and off goes the form.  Works a treat in IE and Firefox, not so in Opera and Chrome.  Just rifled around SO and find that the problem is input#2, which does not have a "name" attribute.  A quick test reveals that when I add name="ignore" it does work indeed in Chrome and Opera.  Only trouble is that the password is now sent across the network plain text, with the label "ignore".  Thanks a bunch.  The whole point of omitting the "name" was to omit that field from the form.

If there a way that I can suppress input#2 from being sent while still giving it a "name"?  Or is there another trick I could use?

Thanks.

Comment: Err, how you you tranfering encryted passwords? Don't say JavaScript, because that won't be a secure encryption.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, so posting as a comment instead - but why are you worried about sending the password over unencrypted. This is what HTTPS is for (encryption at the transport level). Having said that, I'm not sure there's a reliable cross-browser way of doing this. Can you rewrite input#2's value before sending using JS perhaps? That way, it'll get sent over (and the server can ignore it), but it won't be the sensitive value you're worried about.

Comment: Yes, I use JS encryption.  The security of which may be debatable, but it is certainly an improvement on plain text.  My initial plan was to go SSL.  After deliberation, I am resigned to the fact that I cannot trust any client - SSL or not.  Given the considerable overheads that come with SSL (it encrypts tons more than is necessary/useful) I have decided against it.  I could rewrite #2, I suppose, accept the FOC and must revert #2 again when the password is rejected by the server (to allow edit by user).

Comment: @RoTaRa:  Incidentally, I'm intrigued by your blanket dismissal of JS encryption.  I use one-way encryption, eg md5 hash, and only ever handle the hashes.  No decryption ever takes place, so no need for private/public keys.

Comment: The original contents of this comment are no longer relevant since you stated that you use a hash rather than *encryption* (they are not the same thing). However, it brings up a new point: if someone were to intercept it on-the-wire for example, they can just post back the same hash and it is essentially the same as knowing the password. They'll still get access as they'll know the username and the password hash.

Comment: Fair point.  My bad.  Note to self:  must stop using these terms interchangably...

Comment: Yes, the hash is vulnerable.  I presently plan to encrypt the SQL interface, which could take care of the password problem too.  I am just perplexed that the design of Chrome's and Opera's password managers condemns one to send passwords in plain text...

Comment: I'm a little confused what you mean by that, but the reason password managers work that way is because it really is (generally) the best way. HTTPS encrypts the entire transaction and it is only plain before being sent and after it is received.

I really would urge you to have another look and make sure your approach definitely covers all bases security-wise. :)

Comment: It's trade-off.  HTTPS encrypts everything, images, HTML and CSS included.  I don't much care for that stuff.  The only data I care about is that which pertains to my database.  If I can limit my use of private/public key cryptography to just those AJAX exchanges, then that should significantly reduce the load on the server.  And I cannot see what security is added by all those certificates when a determined hacker can simply download the source for Firefox and attack from above the SSL layer.  But this is taking us off-topic some ;-)

Comment: A typical way of addressing your performance concerns is to use HTTPS only for the login page and postback, set a session cookie, and then redirect back to HTTP. You want your server to expire the session cookie after a period of inactivity, but that's built into most frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer in the narrowest sense of the original question is: yes, it is possible via Ajax.  Create a vanilla FORM with two named INPUTs and submit BUTTON.  (Don't forget to feign some action in the FORM attributes.)  Now it looks like a plain-text HTML affair.  Next in JS, intercept the onsubmit from the FORM and launch an Ajax request to your PHP script, POSTing the plain login and *hashed* password.  Return FALSE from onsubmit to suppress the FORM's action.  You're done.  No more plain-text passwords across the wire...